Issue loading r-caret library within conda environment for r
Issue
I am trying to use the caret library but can't use the package due to a dependency issue regarding "reshape2". A simple library(caret) does not work.
Traceback

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'caret' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called 'reshape2'
Traceback:
library(caret)
tryCatch({
attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
error = function(e) {
P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))
paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
else ""
msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",
sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
if (logical.return)
message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
. })
tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
value[3L]
stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

What I Tried...
I have attempted to install "reshape2" as a separate package but it says that the package is already installed. I've tried installing the package several times using conda, mamba, rscript etc. but I'm unable to use the package.

Is this environment fully managed through conda or are there also packages installed from CRAN or other sources? Have you tried with a new, clean, environment?

I'm not able to reproduce this when using  micromamba  in Win10 and having conda-forge as a default channel in .condarc.   micromamba create -n r_env r-base r-caret followed by micromamba run -n r_env RScript -e "library(caret); sessionInfo()" works fine.

Hello margusl,
I created a new environment outside of the base environment and I've gotten the library to work properly. Thank you for your help!
